# Upload and replace the same image file if it already exist

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a picturebox named `PB_Company_Logo` and I have a button named `btn_Save` and within this button I have this `function` which saves the image in `PB_Company_Logo` to `current_directory/images`

```
Public Sub save_PB(PB_Name As PictureBox)
    Dim filename As String = "company_logo.png"
    Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\images"
    Dim filename_path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename)

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
        PB_Name.Image.Save(filename_path)
    Else
        PB_Name.Image.Save(filename_path)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, there are cases where the user will upload a new `company_logo.png`. I want the system to treat the uploading of new image as replacing the former `company_logo.png`.

I think the error in this line of code means that the file is currently in used `(locked)` and therefore cannot be replaced.

```
Else
   PB_Name.Image.Save(filename_path)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load a pictureBox control with an image file the ide (vs) puts a lock on the file. This happens when you set the image property of the pictureBox control to a file at design time.

You can use the FileStream object.
Example:

```
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
' Specify a valid picture file path on your computer.
fs = New System.IO.FileStream("C:\WINNT\Web\Wallpaper\Fly Away.jpg", 
     IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Close()
```

After you have done the workaround you can then use the `System.IO.File.Exists(img)` namespace to check wether or not a picture exists.

Example: This checks if the image passed through already exists and if it does then it will replace it.

```
 Dim imageStr As String = "~/images/name.jpg"

  If System.IO.File.Exists(imageStr) Then
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/name.jpg"
End If
```

Comment: `Image1` means the picture box right? If yes, 'ImageUrl' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'.

Comment: PictureBox is not an actual image, but a control wrapper able to paint an image. You can have to call either .Image or .BackgroundImage

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how to use the code. I must be missing something? I am trying to save the image in `PictureBox` using this code `PictureBox1.Image.Save(filename_path)`

Comment: @DecompileCodex, this works but I am still confused regarding this `Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/name.jpg"`, changing it to `PB_Name.Image.Save(filename_path)` works for me.